# How to get the characteristic polynomial of this matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant, trace, characteristic-polynomial

Consider a $n\times n$ matrix:

$$
M_n = \begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
1 & a_2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & a_3 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots& \vdots& \vdots & \vdots& \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & 1 & a_{n-1} & 1 \\
1 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & 1 & a_n
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where $a_k=2\cos(k\phi)+2\mathrm{i}\gamma\sin(k\phi)$, with $\phi=2\pi/n$ and $0<\gamma<1$. $~n\ge5$, and can be assumed to be prime numbers if necessary.

**How to get its characteristic polynomial $P_n(x)=\det(M_n-xI)$?**

$x^n$, $x^{n-2}$ and $x^0$ terms are easy to get, can you get other terms?

Comment: It does not look nice. For example for $n=5$: $$x^5+5 \left(g^2-2\right) x^3+\frac{5}{2} \left(2 g^4+\sqrt{5} g^2-7 g^2-\sqrt{5}+7\right)
   x-2 \left(5 g^4+10 g^2+2\right).$$

Comment: @user I don't need to get a nice form. Express the coefficients by a summation of some terms (e.g sin cos terms) is OK for me.

Comment: I wonder whether it is not possible to find the traces of the powers of your matrix through induction. In that case, you could find the characteristic polynomial using the Newton-Girard identities. Just a suggestion...

Comment: Last row entries are 1 ... 1  1 or 1 0 ... 0 1?

Comment: @C.F.G see the third row. Basically it is a tridiagonal matrix with nonzero corners

Comment: @anoffercan'trefuse: So the left below entry should be $0$!! isn't?

Comment: @C.F.G it's 1...

Comment: What do you specifically want? Because the suggestion of @R.J. Etienne is right. It gives (very) ugly, but computable characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @jvc What I want is clearly stated. If you think his suggestion is computationable, make it as an answer.

Comment: I am not brave enough to write explicitly the recurrence relations. It is more a suggestion. Because $M_n - x I_n$ has the same structure as $M_n$, we can compute the determinant. By doing cofactor expansion along the first line, and doing other cofactor expansions, we can obtain recurrence relation between $P_n$ and determinants of the same type but in inferior dimension. It will appear tridiagonal determinant which can be computed (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318017/characteristic-polynomial-of-a-tridiagonal-matrix).